# How to modify splash screen in phonegap project?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I have done below things to **make a simple app just to open a mobile website inside app browser**.

- Installed **Phone Gap Desktop App** and created a project
- Build using **Phone Gap Build** and **downloaded APK** for testing on mobile

> Problem : Everything works well expect splash screen is showing
>   default CORDOVA ICON WITH GREY BACKGROUND

I have replaced all the splash screen image inside `\res\screen\android`

And updated my `config.xml` code as well

```
    <platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>


</platform>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

**In index.html** using below script and it open the URL as expected but **splash screen loading default cordova icon with grey background**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    var ref2 = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI('https://example.com'), '_blank', 'location=no');

    navigator.splashscreen.show();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Tried already posted solutions but none of them working for me.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not about cleaning or caching issues at all. The problem is PhoneGap includes all possible launch images in project template by default. These files are under Resources folder and copied to bundle's root folder on build event. Although I properly selected my own launch images in Xcode (Target/Summary screen), default PhoneGap's specific files e.g. Default~iphone.png overridden my files :(

Once issue is identified, you can fix it someway, but I prefer below steps:

1. Delete all default icons and splashscreen files under
       /platforms/ios/AppName/icons and /splash folders. You surely don't
       need these placeholder images.
2. In Xcode, select Targets/AppName, then tab Build Phases, delete all
   file names of images in the above step in section Copy Bundle
   Resources.
3. Add your own images files for app icon and launch images here.
4. Edit Info.plist file (file AppName-Info.plist under
       /platforms/ios/AppName/) to include your images, you will need to
       use CFBundleIcons and UILaunchImageFile keys. Go to iOS developer
       site for reference.

Comment: I am using Phone Gap Build for building app for ios/android/windows ... Icons works very well only splash screen is not changing

Comment: @ManojDeswal it's same for splash screens too

Comment: When building using phonegap build , we only get end file to use , that's .apk file . no access to /platforms/ios/AppName/icons as you are saying. I am only working with Phonegap tools.

Comment: Sir, before build you must locate splashscreen / icons and change them (if you want it) - [check this out](https://imgur.com/a/pjoPE)

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have changed them , icons works well but splash screen doesn't